# Does Ubuntu 12.04 have video drivers for Nvidia Quadro or AMD Firepro GPU's?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, ati, graphics

I was building a Workstation for video production and I wanted to use ether a AMD Firepro Or Nvidia Quadro Graphics Card. I am very much a fan of Ubuntu and I was wondering if 12.04 supported any of those cards and If so, which ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can install drivers for both graphics cards:

Installation instructions for AMD drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases libelfg0 execstack build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 ia32-libs; sudo apt-get -f install
wget -O ati-amd-v2.4-NoobsLab64.deb http://goo.gl/dylWp
sudo dpkg -i ati-amd-v2.4-NoobsLab64.deb; rm ati-amd-v2.4-NoobsLab64.deb
```

Installation instructions for Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```